# How to handle success and failure for Ajax http post with JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, jackson

I do an http post with JQuery 2.0.3 this way:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/demo/submitTransactions",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConfirmedTransactions: confirmedTransactions }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){alert(data);},
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

The json gets posted and written at the server but the response `success:` and `failure:` are not enabled AFAIK. The controller code that received the json data is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitTransactions", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public String submitTransactions(@RequestBody @Valid final String string) {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)));
            out.println("\n"+string);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.severe("IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.info("Received transactions "+string);
        return "Received JSON data";
    }
```

How can I also make the success and failure get the callback that the posted json was successfully received or failed to submit? It works to submit the data but the response from the server `"Received JSON data"`doesn't do anything and there is no difference between this and a controller method that is `void` and just writes the data with no `return`statement. Can you suggest an improvement so that the javascript that posts the data also receives the response which I suppose would be either status 200 OK or perhaps status 500 or similar if there was a server error?

According to answer by @Oleg Estekhin it should be more like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/demo/submitTransactions",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConfirmedTransactions: confirmedTransactions }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    })
            .done(function(data){alert('Done!'+data);})
            .fail(function(errMsg) {alert('Failure!'+errMsg);});
```

Now if I also change the controller code to a response object using jackson

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitTransactions2", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public AccountResponse submitTransactions2(@RequestBody @Valid final String string) {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)));
        out.println("\n"+string);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.severe("IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.info("Received transactions "+string);
    return new AccountResponse("Received transactions ", "Received ", "Received ", "Received ");
}

Then I get the response "Done!" from the server (but I get the response "failed" when using just a string and no jackson.

[image]

After updating according to the second answer, this change seems to work:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/demo/submitTransactions",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConfirmedTransactions: confirmedTransactions }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text"
    })
            .done(function(data){alert('Done!'+data);})
            .fail(function(errMsg) {alert('Failure!'+errMsg);});
```

It works. [image]ives tha returned `String`

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in answer from Oleg Estekhin, the correct property to use is `error`. Also you should use the promise variants:

```
$.ajax({ ... })
 .done(...)
 .fail(...);
```

Next you should change `dataType` to `text` so that jQuery knows that the returned value is to be parsed as normal text and not as JSON. This will result in the success callback to be called. The final code will then look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/demo/submitTransactions",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConfirmedTransactions: confirmedTransactions }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text"
    })
     .done(function(data){alert(data);})
     .fail(function(errMsg) {alert(errMsg);})
     ;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, per [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation the property that contains a failure callback is called "error", so your example should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // other properties
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    error: function(errMsg) {alert(errMsg);}
});
```

Second, "success", "error" and "complete" callbacks are considered deprecated since jQuery 1.8, and you should use promise-style variants:

```
$.ajax({
    // other properties
})
.done(function(data){alert(data);})
.fail(function(errMsg) {alert(errMsg);});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use JQuery 2.0.3 and I'm updating the answer with this.